# Wifite Issue, "enabling monitor mode on phy3."

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux

Running Kali, recently got TL-WN772N adapter, for some reason at the start of Wifite it gives me the choice of which interface to select, it seems that enables the monitor mode then goes straight back to selecting an interface. I've tried fluxion and it I selected wlan1 (TL-WN772N) and it worked perfectly.

I've tried disabling wlan0 by adding `iface wlan0 inet manual` to `/etc/network/interfaces` also `ifconfig wlan0 down`.

I am fairly new to Linux, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 .;'                     `;,    
 .;'  ,;'             `;,  `;,   WiFite v2 (r87)
.;'  ,;'  ,;'     `;,  `;,  `;,  
::   ::   :   ( )   :   ::   ::  automated wireless auditor
':.  ':.  ':. /_\ ,:'  ,:'  ,:'  
 ':.  ':.    /___\    ,:'  ,:'   designed for Linux
  ':.       /_____\      ,:'     
           /       \             


 [+] scanning for wireless devices...
 [+] available wireless devices:
  1. phy3   wlan0       ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
  2. phy2   wlan1       ath9k_htc   Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
 [+] select number of device to put into monitor mode (1-2): 1
 [+] enabling monitor mode on phy3... done
 [+] available wireless devices:
  1. phy3   wlan0       ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
  2. phy2   wlan1       ath9k_htc   Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
 [+] select number of device to put into monitor mode (1-2): 2
 [+] enabling monitor mode on phy2... done
 [+] available wireless devices:
  1. phy3   wlan0       ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
  2. phy2   wlan1       ath9k_htc   Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
 [+] select number of device to put into monitor mode (1-2):
```

Comment: You don't need to use the TL-WN772N  wifi  adapter ,  the AR9485  support the monitir mode

Comment: I know, I used it previously but I'm using this adapter now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable `wlan0` , unload the `ath9k` driver:

```
 rmmod ath9k
```

To disable it at boot add the following line to your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist ath9k
```

To enable it again , remove  `blacklist ath9k` from `blacklist.conf` and run:

```
modprobe ath9k
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it out. rmmod ath9k worked for me right away, added blacklist ath9k to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf so I'll restart and test it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already tried the `ifconfig wlan0 down` / `up` routine, try to run also: 
`airmon-ng check kill`

It will kill some of the conflicting processes (like Network Manager). Probably this will be enough. Also it's worth noticing that the TL-WN772N has two versions with different chipsets. If you have v2, I think you're out of luck.